# Ionic3 Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: push-notification, ionic3

I have been dealing with this for the past 2 weeks now.I'm building an application with Ionic3. Everything worked fine, Untill I install phonegap push plugin. Then I start to get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateExce ption: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files
```

I have made research about this and none of the solution seemed to work for me. I have done  below to app level build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

i also added below code

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Then I started gettin below error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write 
[C:\ionic\brinmiz\platforms\android\app\build
\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read 
[C:\ionic\brinmiz\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\17.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [17.jar:android/support/v4/media/RatingCompat$1.class]))
```

This is my Ionic info

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.10.2
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 8
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Dd\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Like I said, I have been on this for the past 2 weeks. I really need your solution

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#multidex) by the official documentation of Push Plugin, there is a known incompatibility between Push Plugin and another plugins that "are using an outdated way to declare dependencies such as **android-support** or **play-services-gcm**".

You can try to install **cordova-android-support-gradle-release** that will align various versions of the Android Support libraries specified by other plugins to a specific version.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --fetch
```

Also you can try to downgrade your **cordova-android** from 7.0.0 to 6.3.0 because there are also known issues with 7.x+. Delete your plugin folder(make sure you have all of them declared in config.xml) and run:

```
cordova platforms rm android
cordova platforms add android@6.3.0
```

If nothing do the job, update your answer with all the plugins used by your application using the next command and I will try to debug for you.

```
cordova plugin ls
```

Comment: I created a fresh project and I added d phonegap push plugin and I worked. So it's definitely one of d plugin I installed that was causing d error. But before I talk about that. For d New project I created, when ever I install it on a device and try to open I just get "unfortunately appname stopped working". Please what could be d cause.

Comment: What version of cordova-android did you use for the new project and what android version on device? Can you also try to fix your initial project and reply with the result here?

Comment: Tank you so much. I believe as you said, the problem has to do with android 7. I installed android 6.3.0 as u said and everyhing is perfect now. Thank alot